# When 2 threads would be executed on a 1 physical CPU core with a multi-core CPU machine?

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, linux-kernel, scheduler, scheduling

Lets say there's a machine with 8-cores CPU.

I'm creating 2 posix threads using standard `pthread_create(...)` function.

As I know there's no any garanties these threads always would be executed by a 2 different physical cores, but practically in 90% they **will** run simultaneously (or in parallel). At least for my cases I seen that `top` command shows 2 cpu's are running ... thus around 160-180% CPU usage

The question is:

What could be the scenario when 2 threads within a single process are running only on 1 physical core ?

Comment: That's easy.  Never, (unless you consider hyperthreads as one core).

Comment: @MartinJames what are hyperthreads ?

Comment: @MartinJames hyperthreading ?

Comment: ' hyperthreading ?' yes, or similar hardware optimizations of one CPU core that may allow one core to 'run two threads', kind-of.

Comment: @nos having the kernel dispatch the two threads to the same physical core at different times is not really what the OP asked, IME, (I may be wrong... :).

Comment: @MartinJames yes the question isn't about that

Comment: @MartinJames so enabled hyperthreading would make 2 threads executing on a single core frequently than disabled ?

Comment: Do you mean executing at the same time? In alternation? Or either way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two cases:

1) The other physical cores are busy doing other stuff, so only one core gets used by this process. The two threads run in alternation on that core.

2) The physical core supports executing more than one thread concurrently using hyperthreading or something similar. The other physical cores are busy doing other stuff, so the best the scheduler can do is run both threads in a single physical core.

Comment: It gets you about a 10-20% performance boost (depending on workload) and only uses about 4% more space on the die and about 8% more power. What don't you understand?

Comment: I mean what relation hyperthreading has to a case when 2 threads are executing on single/multiple physical cores on a multicore machine ?

Comment: Hyperthreading is a technology that allows more than one thread at a time to run on the same physical core. Without HT, or some similar technology, each physical core can only execute one thread at a time.

Comment: so no run in alternation at all ??

Comment: They can run in alternation without HT. HT allows them to run at the same time. If a physical core has HT, there are two of all the per-thread resources such as registers. They share execution units.